# PhpStorm MySql Double Quotes Literal interpreted as Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, phpstorm

I am newbie to PhpStorm. 
I have a mysql-query:

```
$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `FLAP_Messages` WHERE `placeId` = ? AND `type` = "orgwall"   AND `Status` = ?';
```

And PhpStorm give me a warning - unable to resolve column "orgwall". If I change double quotes to single quotes warning disappear. How can I tell to PhpStorm to allow double quotes in string literals in MySQL queries?

Comment: What's wrong with single quotes?

Comment: Why do you need to? Double quotes for column names is actually the standard (backticks are a mysql extension).

Comment: Single quotes is OK, but I will have to replace all double quotes in all queries in existing project just to eliminate warnings.

Comment: "Double quotes for column names is actually the standard" - if so, it's another reason to replace them to single quotes in literals.

Answer (score 6):

There is a fix for this is PHPStorm. Open

Preferences > Editor > Inspections > SQL > Unresolved reference > Checkbox - Suppress for quoted identifiers which may be treated as strings

Answer (score 5):

> How can I tell to PhpStorm to allow double quotes in string literals in MySQL queries?

Currently you cannot change this behaviour, unless you use single quotes for string values instead of double quotes.

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-44162
- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99644

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is related, but since this was the first question I found on Stack Overflow related to my problem (showing backticks as errors in string literals), I'm putting my solution here.

For OSX, it was Preferences/SQL Dialect, set to `MySQL` project-wide.

Answer (score 1):

In phpStorm 9.0 on Ubuntu I had to change the Project SQL dialect

File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > SQL Dialects > Click Project Directory & Click  SQL Dialect and change it to MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This is an old subject, and good answers have already been given, but as I had the same problem, and didn't want to wrap my query in double quotes, I finally used NOWDOC syntax, like this :

```
$query = <<<'QUERY'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `FLAP_Messages` WHERE `placeId` = ? AND `type` = 'orgwall'   AND `Status` = ?
QUERY;
```

Comment: Unfortunately in 2019.3 it doesn't work. Even with correct SQL-dialect it keeps interpreting double quotes as column identifiers.

Comment: That may habe been a temporary workaround, thanks for the update.